# Navigation settings in SP 2010/2013: how to recreate Global navigation and current navigation

Tags: navigation, site-settings

see the image taken from the internet

[image]

How to make Global Navigation and Current Navigation 'folders' reappear?

Answer (score 2):

How could they delete that from site settings in Navigation menu? I logged in as site collection administrator and I could not even see the delete option enabled.

Have you checked the masterpage of the site to see if the GlobalNavigation section is deleted or missing?

[image]

Comment: Yes , It can't be deleted even by site collection administrator . its is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

those 2 disappear when you select Display the same navigation items as the parent site. Selecting Display navigation below the parent site will make them available again